# Does Collections.rotate() operate on all the elements if used on a list of lists?

Tags: java, collections

I am writing a Keyword in Context program. For circular shifting the sentence I thought of using `Collections.rotate()`.

So I am taking a sentence as a List of characters. Then I rotate the sentence and `.add(this.sentences)` to get a list of sentences which I will be sorting in the next module.

Now, it does the rotation correctly but whenever I add it to the list of sentences, it rotates the previously added sentence too. And I am totally lost why its doing that.

I have commented an example output in the code itself. In the last line it should print out `{A stormy night}, {stormy night A}`

I would appreciate it if you could help out.

```
public void shift(List<Character> sentence)
    {
        sentences = new ArrayList<>();
        sentences.add(sentence); //adds the first un-rotated sentence to the list.
        //count the words.
        int words = 0;
        for(char ch: sentence)
        {
            if(ch == ' ')
                words++;
        }
        //for each word, rotate.
        for(int i = 0; i<words; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int distance = 0;
            for(char c: sentence)
            {
                count++;
                if(c == ' ')
                {
                    distance = count;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Sentences: " + sentences);//output: A stormy night

            Collections.rotate(sentence, (0 - distance));

            System.out.println("sentence after rotation: " + sentence);//stormy night a 

            this.sentences.add(sentence);

            System.out.println("sentences after adding: " + sentences);//{stormy night a}, {stormy night a}
            
        }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.rotate` mutates the list by rotating it. You are always rotating the exact same list. You have to copy the rotated sentence before adding it to the list to avoid your problem.

Comment: As marstran said, you need to copy the list. Besides that, consider the simplicity of `sentence.indexOf(' ')` over your search loop. Further, instead of `(0 - distance)` you can simply write `-distance`. And when you keep track of the total shift and stop once it reaches the list’s size, you don’t need to count the words beforehand, `sentences = new ArrayList<>(); for(int total = 0;;) { this.sentences.add(sentence); int distance = sentence.indexOf(' ') + 1; total += distance; if(total >= sentence.size()) break; sentence = new ArrayList<>(sentence); Collections.rotate(sentence, -distance); }`